# How to assign containers specific IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in Docker

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, ip

I have a Debian 10 Buster machine running with the latest Docker from the external and official repository. My goal is to let the container only listen for these two (example) IP addresses on port 80:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    network_mode: host # I need it to see the clients IPs
    ports:
      - 100.100.100.100:80:80
      - 1000:1000:1000:1000::1:80:80
    command:
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.watch=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"

nginx: [...]
```

But even after restarting the containers and the whole server itself, the server was still listening to all IPs:

**netstat -tulpn**

```
Proto  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address  Foreign Address State   PID/Program name
tcp6        0       0  :::80          :::*            LISTEN  2170/traefik        
tcp6        0       0  :::443         :::*            LISTEN  2170/traefik
```

Comment: If you say `network_mode: host`, none of the rest of Docker networking has any effect, and it's up to your process to bind to the correct addresses.  (IME it's also usually a hacky workaround, particularly for HTTP services.)

Comment: Oh interesting. Alright, but how do I expose the clients IP to the container then? Because the HTTP service only shows the internal Docker IP.